# Proof: Optimality in the convex case

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization

I have just started to learn non linear programming (through the well named D.Bertsekas book) and I am struggling to understand one of the [basic proofs](https://books.google.fr/books?ei=UvV7TYHMAu-80QGBnOTQAw&ct=result&redir_esc=y&hl=fr&id=QeweAQAAIAAJ&dq=Bertsekas+nonlinear+programming&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=Proposition+1.1.3) in the convex case:

Let $X$ be a convex set and $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function over $X$. If $X$ is open and $f$ continuously differentiable over $X$, then $\nabla f (x^{\ast}) = 0$  is a necessary and sufficient condition for a vector $x^{\ast} \in X$ to be a global minimum of $f$ over $X$.

For the optimality of this condition, I am ok. I am struggling with the other side of the proof:

> To arrive at a contradiction, assume that $x^{\ast}$ minimizes $f$
> over $X$ and that $\nabla f (x^{\ast}) \neq 0$. Then since $X$ is open
> and $x^{\ast} \in X$, there must be an open ball centered at
> $x^{\ast}$ that is contained in $X$. **Thus for some $x \in X$ we have
> $\nabla f (x^{\ast})'(x - x^{\ast}) < 0$**.

I don't understand the implication in bold. I have a clear idea of what is an open ball and of some basic properties about convex sets and functions, but I didn't find any combinations of my current knowledge of these subjects to explain this. Anyone has an explanation about this?

Comment: are you sure about the ordering of $x$ and $x^*$ here? I thought this would just fall out of the subgradient inequality $\langle \nabla f(y) \,,\, x-y\rangle + f(y) \leq f(x)$ but maybe i'm missing something.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, I guess this doesn't come from the subgradient inequality. It is used in another proof concerning the condition $\nabla f ( x^{\ast} ) ' (x - x^{\ast} ) \geq 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(t)= f(tv + x^*)$ for some nonzero $v$ in the ball contained in $X$, I.e. take $v=x-x^*$ for some $x$,then $$t\leq 0 \implies\frac{g(t) - g(0)}{t}\leq 0,$$ since $x^*$ is a minimiser. Taking the left-side limit $t\downarrow 0$, which exists by the existence of $\nabla f(x^*)$, then $$g’(0)=\nabla f(x^*)^Tv\leq 0.$$ But $v$ and $\nabla f(x^*)$ nonzero implies that the inequality is strict, a contradiction.

Comment: $v$ and $\Delta f(x^*)$ nonzero does not imply that their scalar product must be strictly nonzero! e.g., $[-1, 1]^\top [1, -1] = 0 $ is a scalar product of two strictly nonzero vectors. I think you may need to do a bit of case analysis to finish the proof.

Comment: @Zim Yes, that is a very important remark, but the point here is that $v$ is chosen arbitrarily from the interior of the ball, so we can pick $v$ s.t. the inner product is positive (take for example $v=a\nabla f(x^*)$ for some $a > 0$). I will edit the answer later to include this.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. your comment makes things clearer for me, we can easily find an $x$ in the interior point of the ball so that $\nabla f (x^*) ^T (x - x^*) < 0$ using a similar example! I will write an answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's take $x = -a \nabla f (x^*) + x^*$ with $a > 0$ and s.t. $a || \nabla f (x ^*) || < r$ with $r$ the radius of the open ball in $X$.

$x$ is then in the open ball centered in $x^*$ as $||x - x^*|| = a|| \nabla f (x ^*) || < r$.

We have finally $\nabla f (x ^*)^T (x - x^*) = - a || \nabla f (x ^*) || < 0$